# Will a tooltip work, when an control is in non-visible mode

Tags: tooltip

I have a basic question on tooltip.
Will a tooltip work if a control say for ex: textbox is set as in-visible mode and a mouse by mistake moved over the invisible textbox. [ understood tooltip will still work if the text box is in non-editable mode]

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would help if you posted what language/framework your using...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your toolkit. The most toolkits will disable tooltips for invincible elements, since there is no point to display them.